# transport stream - extracting information

Tags: c++, video-streaming, video-capture, transport-stream

I have entire mux with four channels dumped in a single *.ts file.
I'm demultiplexing that and I can't find any info on how to extract the resolution, framerate, codec, language, channels, etc...

Should I read macroblocks, or do something else?

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the listing of where to look for the information:

1. Number of programs, their description etc. : PAT and PMT.
2. The number of Audio and languages and additional information : SDT, BAT etc.
3. Codec - refer to PES header - stream_id and look up in MPEG 2 systems standard.
4. Resolution, and frame rate, 4.2.0/4.2.2 - sequence header in MPEG 2 video elementary stream.
5. Bitrate - you can only *estimate* by counting number of packets(x 188bytes) between two PCR packets and the PCR distance.

Append your question for more specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just demultiplexing, it suffices to read the PAT and PMT and split the streams based on their PIDs, and create new PATs and PMTs for the streams.

Something like gstreamer or vlc may be helpful as it already has a lot of code for manipulating transport streams.

Comment: You are right, demultiplexing itself does not depend on the data I would like to extract, such as resolution, framerate etc... But, since I'm demuxing, I would like to know what exactly is inside.

Comment: Just for demultiplexing raw TS packets, yes. But, for additional information like resolution, audio format etc... PAT and PMT will not help, because these tables doesn't contain that information. Perhaps I should read the sequence header...